# Returning a list of <li> WebElements via find_element_by_xpath

Tags: xpath, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

So I am using a combination of Selenium and Python 2.7 (and if it matters the browser I am in is Firefox). I am new to XPath but it seems very useful for fetching WebElements.

I have the following HTML file that I am parsing through:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    ..
    <div id="childItem">
      <ul>
        <li class="listItem"><img/><span>text1</span></li>
        <li class="listItem"><img/><span>text2</span></li>
        ...
        <li class="listItem"><img/><span>textN</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I can use the following code to get a list of all the li elements:

```
root  = element.find_element_by_xpath('..')
child = root.find_element_by_id('childDiv')
list  = child.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.childDiv > ul > li.listItem')
```

I am wondering how I can do this in an XPath statement. I have tried a few statments but the most simple is:

```
list  = child.find_element_by_xpath('li[@class="listItem"]')
```

But I always end up getting the error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"li[@class=\\"listItem\\"]"}';`

As I do have a work around (the first three lines) this is not critical for me, but I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `.//` at the start of the xpath:

```
list  = child.find_element_by_xpath('.//li[@class="listItem"]')
```

The `.//` means to search anywhere within the `child` element.

Comment: so ``.`` is the current element then ``//`` means any children of it?

Comment: Yes. Note that if you do just `//` (ie without the `.`), the xpath will search anywhere on the page, including those that are not a descendent of `child`.

Comment: That is a huge help. Thanks!